# How can I import the type for CommonFindController from monaco-editor?

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

I'm using monaco-editor, and recently I started using TS. However, this code started producing an error, saying `start` does not exist:

```js
      const findController = editor.getContribution("editor.contrib.findController");
      findController.start({});
```

I looked at the types, and I found I needed to provide the expected type to `getContribution`. After some exploring, I found [where it was defined](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/667d4629dee90744edd5054f13bc2452c8c14490/src/vs/editor/contrib/find/browser/findController.ts#L88). However, despite findController being shipped in monaco-editor, I can't find the typings. `monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/find/browser/findController.d.ts` only says `export {}`.
Where am I supposed to get the typings?